# Error when trying to get a number in JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm getting an error while trying to get a number value using JSON decode in PHP.

My json data:

```
{
    "nameFile": "Tester file.txt",
    "ext": "txt",
    "scanResult": "Valid",
    "size": 8107
}
```

My php code:

```
$decode = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo $decode["size"];
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'size' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\getdata.php on line 10 {

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Print_r($decode)`, what do you see?

Comment: Yo @u_mulder, See http://i.imgur.com/nfzvU3c.png

Comment: Nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSON because you are doing correct but if you want to prevent error then you can try this

```
$decode = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo isset($decode["size"]) ? $decode["size"] : 'not found';
```